# Why isn't Roundcube's Upgrade Shell Script Working?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, bash, scripts, roundcube

I am trying to upgrade my Roundcube installation from version `1.0.4` to `1.0.5` and I cannot get the upgrade script working properly. According to Roundcube's [upgrade documentation](http://trac.roundcube.net/browser/github/UPGRADING), the following command should upgrade Roundcube (Assuming the distro is Ubuntu 14.04):

`$ cd roundcubemail-1.0.5 && sudo bash bin/installto.sh /var/www/html/roundcube`

When I run the command, some junk gets printed to my Terminal and no upgrading occurs.

```
./bin/installto.sh: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
./bin/installto.sh: line 3: /bin: Is a directory
./bin/installto.sh: line 4: +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+: command not found
./bin/installto.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./bin/installto.sh: line 5: ` | bin/installto.sh                                                      |'
```

Does anyone know what is wrong, what I am doing wrong or why this is not working? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `installto.sh` is not a linux shell script, though it ends with `.sh`. It is a PHP file that is meant to be run from the command line. To successfully upgrade Roundcube, it needs to be executed as follows:

```
cd roundcubemail-1.0.5 && sudo php bin/installto.sh /var/www/html/roundcube
```

My mistake was I was trying to run the script using `bash` instead of `php`.